# Pre-Calculus Question: g(x) = $\sqrt[4]{x^2-6x}$ -- Find the Domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't for the life of me understand why the answer to this questions is $(-\infty,0] \cup [6,\infty)$

However, when I set the expression $x^2-6x \geq 0$, I get $x \geq 0$ and $x \geq 6$. Thus, I have the domain $[6, \infty) \cup [0,\infty)$.

What am I failing to understand?

Comment: Have you sketched a plot of $x^2-6x$ to get some idea where it's positive and where it's negative?

Answer (score 3):

The domain is the set of points where $x^2 - 6x = x(x - 6)\ge 0$; thus, both $x$ and $x - 6$ must share the same sign. That is, we need either to have both $x$ and $x - 6$ nonnegative, or we need both $x$ and $x - 6$ to be non-positive.

If they are both nonnegative, $x \ge 6$; if they are both nonpositive, $x \le 0$ (alternatively, you can see this by testing points in the intervals $(-\infty, 0), (0, 6)$ and $(6, \infty)$. Combining this, the domain should be

$$(-\infty, 0] \cup [6, \infty)$$

Comment: So I have to create a diagram and take the positive values?

Comment: @user137452 That's one way to do it (alternatively, study the pairs of signs as I did in my answer).

Comment: Okay. I think I understand. Since the function is a quadratic inequality, I have to make a diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You need $x^2 - 6x \ge 0$. Factor to see that the inequality becomes
$$x(x-6) \ge 0.$$
Use the fact that $AB \ge 0$ iff $A$ and $B$ have the same sign.